# How do I find the path of intersection between functions in R?

Tags: r, optimization, intersection, gaussian

I'm trying to figure out how to find points in a two-dimensional field where one multivariate function is equal to another. More specifically, gaussians:

```
g1 <- function(x){x1 = x[1]; x2 = x[2]; return (1.2 / (sqrt(4 * pi * pi * 81)) * exp(-1/18*((x1-12)**2 + (x2-3))) + .4 / (sqrt(4 * pi * pi * 81)) * exp(-1/18*((x1-3)**2 + (x2-5)**2)) )}

g2 <- function(x){x1 = x[1]; x2 = x[2]; return (.8 / (sqrt(4 * pi * pi * 81)) * exp(-1/18*((x1-4)**2 + (x2-12))) + .2 / (sqrt(4 * pi * pi * 81)) * exp(-1/18*((x1-3)**2 + (x2-5)**2)) )}

g3 <- function(x){x1 = x[1]; x2 = x[2]; return (1.2 / (sqrt(4 * pi * pi * 81)) * exp(-1/18*((x1-4)**2 + (x2-12))) + .4 / (sqrt(4 * pi * pi * 81)) * exp(-1/18*((x1-12)**2 + (x2-3)**2)) )}
```

Here, I've already decomposed the matrix Sigma into simple algebra. I want to find the curves that represent g1(x) == g2(x), g1(x) == g3(x), and g2(x) == g3(x). Do I need to simply do a double for loop and use some threshold (e.g., abs(g1 - g2) < 1E-5)? I'd like something a bit more robust.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you just form composite functions of the differences and solve of 0? The family of curves for solutions at various levels of difference is well plotted with contourplots There are worked examples of plotting the contour where the value is zero. Have you done any searching on SO?

Comment: Ah, this is what I was looking for. I'm pretty new to R, so excuse my ignorance. Thank you!